# Only one parent travelling back from US to EU with dual citizen child

Tags: us-citizens, eu-citizens, iceland, minors, icelandair

There are already several questions on this site regarding travel with a minor and only one parent, but I don't think this specific situation has already been covered:

My wife, me, and our minor child live in Germany, but we're currently on vacation in the US (we traveled there together). It turns out that I will be traveling back to Germany alone with our child (my wife will be returning a few days later than us). Our child is a dual US/German citizen. We'll be traveling with Icelandair, changing planes in Iceland (that is, we'll re-enter the Schengen area in Iceland).

Which additional documents do we need for that? So far, we have a [parental consent form](https://res.cloudinary.com/adacde/image/upload/v1571650853/ADAC-eV/KOR/Text/PDF/vollmacht-mit-vater-reisendes-kind_z2ri0y.pdf) signed by my wife, and our child's birth certificate (which proves that my wife is indeed the mother). Will that suffice or do we need anything else?

Comment: You'll be fine. My wife and I have travelled with our 3 kids between the US and Germany in any possible permutation dozens of time with just our normal travel documentation (passports, green cards, etc). We never carried a consent letter or birth certificates etc. and no one ever asked for anything.

Comment: @Hilmar do the five of you have the same surname(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which additional documents do we need for that?

Nothing, with that form you're even better off than most

Comment: So, yeah, that was a huge nothingburger. US TSA check didn't care at all. The Icelandic officer asked me where the mother was, but didn't want to see any documents.